# Jupyter notebook note importing modules directly

Tags: python, numpy, module, jupyter-notebook

I have recently run into an issue where i uninstalled anaconda and installed jupyter directly in from cmd and it is stored in this path

```
C:\Users\karth\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts
```

for some reason now I can't even import NumPy even though it says that NumPy install is satisfied

> !pip install
> numpy

```
Requirement already satisfied: NumPy in c:\users\karth\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages (1.21.6)
```

but when I try to open and run the module in jupyter it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [7], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 a = [1,2,3]
      3 b = [4,5,6]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

need some help

Comment: My guess is that jupyter is not using the same interpreter as the one you installed numpy to.

Comment: Within your jupyter notebook you may want to try to run this line: `%pip install numpy`

Comment: it shows an error because Numpy not present in interpreter path, but it said requirement satisfied because numpy is present in anacondas path